# How to open new browser window using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to open new browser window using java script window.open, i have html page but it getting error as page not found.This is from jsf/icefaces.I have display the html page directly.Please help me...

```
    JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),
"window.open('printerFriendly.html','Print',,'width=300','height=200','menubar=yes',
'status=yes','location=yes','toolbar=yes','scrollbars=yes')");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
<FORM>
<INPUT type="button" value="New Window!" onClick="window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes,
location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,
resizable=yes')">
</FORM>
```

It's in a form, but the JS code would be the same for any other link.

Answer (score 2):

Opening a New Window With JavaScript

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

Javascript (JS) Tutorial - opening new browser window using open ...

http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/open-method.php

Answer (score 0):

window.open opens new browser window. If you getting page not found error, may be you should check that the page exists?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is correct, you need to correct the URL ('printerFriendly.html').

Answer (score 0):

Page Not Found is Page Not Found. Check if the URL is correct. Is `printerFriendly.html` located in the same folder as your current page? It should be. Or you should provide the correct path.