# How could I accomplish a popup modal window (Example included)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open new browser window using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616709/how-to-open-new-browser-window-using-javascript)

For example: http://www.nowness.com/ > Click "Twitter"

I'm not asking about the Twitter API, just a generic window that I want to open up. jQuery can be used.

edit: Modal was the wrong term here. I wanted a popup, not a modal.

Comment: A modal dialog is not a generic window. What exactly do you want?

Comment: The popup window is not modal. A modal window would prevent interaction with the other window(s) until you've closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add your link

```
<a class="tweetme" 
   href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=yourtext&url=yoururl">
   Tweet Me
</a>
```

and the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.tweetme').click(function (event) {
        var width = 575,
                height = 400,
                left = ($(window).width() - width) / 2,
                top = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
                url = this.href,
                opts = 'status=1' +
                        ',width=' + width +
                        ',height=' + height +
                        ',top=' + top +
                        ',left=' + left;

        window.open(url, 'twitte', opts);

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user jQuery UI.
Here's the tutorial and demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Sorry, I need it to open in a new window