# How to open a aspx page as Modal popup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, modal-dialog

How to open a aspx page as Modal popup.

1. Test.aspx should open like a modal popup.
2. Let Test1.aspx has one button. On click it should populate Test.aspx page as Modal          popup.

   Here is my button:

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Fill Form in Popup" />
   ```

NOTE: Test.aspx : Normal aspx page but Test1.aspx: Parent page Contain master page.

Comment: Do you want to open this on popup as a "Modal Dialog" in a separate window?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open this as jQuery model dialog, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546132/how-could-i-accomplish-a-popup-modal-window-example-included) post

Otherwise, If you want to open this page in a Modal Dialog you can use the following code to open it up. This examples use **window.showModalDialog** method of javascript. To find details how to use you can refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
      <script>
        function fnRandom(iModifier) {
          return parseInt(Math.random() * iModifier);
        }

        function fnSetValues() {
          var oForm = document.getElementById('oForm');
          var iHeight = oForm.oHeight.options[oForm.oHeight.selectedIndex].text;

          if (iHeight.indexOf("Random") > -1) {
            iHeight = fnRandom(document.body.clientHeight);
          }

          var sFeatures = "dialogHeight: " + iHeight + "px;";
          return sFeatures;
        }

        function fnOpen() {
          var sFeatures = fnSetValues();
          window.showModalDialog("test.aspx", "", sFeatures)
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: window.showModalDialog is no longer being supported in IE or Chrome. And will probably be deprecated soon in Firefox. see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`,try this

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim query As String = "test.aspx" 
        Dim newWin As String = "window.open('" & query & "');"
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "pop", newWin, True)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use modal popup extender like below.

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="Button1"
CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="Background">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Reference : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/open-a-new-web-form-in-the-model-popup-of-Asp-Net-applicatio/

Or you can use jquery for opening a modal dialog with asp.net something like.

```
$(document).on("click", "#LoadDialogButton", function () {

var url = "DialogContentPage.aspx";
var divId = " #MainContentDiv";

var q1 = "?inp1=" + $("#Input1").val();
var q2 = "&inp2=" + $("#Input2").val();

url = url + q1 + q2 + divId; //url in the form 'DialogContentPage.aspx?inp1=xx&inp2=yy #MainContentDiv'

$('<div id=DialogDiv>').dialog("destroy");

$('<div id=DialogDiv>').dialog({
    dialogClass: 'DynamicDialogStyle',
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load(url);           
    },
    close: function (e) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    },
    height: 350,
    width: 540,
    title: 'Dynamic Dialog'

});
```

});

Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488312/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-with-Dynamic-Content

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple javascript to open aspx page in new window /popup

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/");
window.open("~/mypage.aspx");
```

or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('YourPage.aspx?Param=" + ParamX.ToString() + "');",true);
```

Or if you have a button you can use it as below:

```
Button1.OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('YourPage.aspx?Param=" + ParamX.ToString() + "');";
```

hope this will help you otherwise use Ajax modal popup.