# How to open new browser window (not tab) and then resize it using jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a web application, which will mostly be used in my own company (for internal usage). Since the application's UI is not much, so I though that it would be a good idea to make a website target for low resolution (400x600 resolution) and when a client (from PC browser) makes a request to website,

- I would open a new window ([How to open new browser window using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616709/how-to-open-new-browser-window-using-javascript))
- In the new window my website would be displayed.

So it would just look like a chat-type-of messenger app. But there are two things extra which I want to do. `(See attached screenshot, of what happens till now)`

- Currently (using above code), I am able to open new window, but original window (tab) is not closed. **I want to close it**
- Second, I want to set the position of new window to right lower corner, **How can I do that ?**

**Can someone please help ?**

[image]

Comment: I think you are asking for popup window of browser

Comment: @Ankur140290 Yes, kind of. But I want to set the position of a pop-up window

Comment: use `window.close()` in addition to the existing code ?

Comment: @MrBones I did not help.. no closing... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall do you the trick:

```
<button onclick="openNewWidow(500,100)" > OPen </button>

<script language="javascript">

function openNewWidow(width, height) {
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight) - height - 100);
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth) - (width / 2));
    var features = "location=1, status=1, scrollbars=1, width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left;
    window.open("test.html", "kad", features);
    window.close();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Great !!1 It works, Only problem is that the window touches the lower bottom (i.e. goes behind the start taskbar in windows) Can that be fixed ?

Comment: try this `var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight) - height - 100);` where we are shifting the window and extra 100 top without dividing the height.